# Wny Linux sends unicode keyboard events while Windows sends ANSI

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3

Unde linux, the foreign keys such as ü Ü do not seem to work with this code:

String.fromCharCode(e.charCode).toLowerCase();

The output is wrong under Linux, but Windows is Ok.

Here is sample page to debug this:
the output of foreign keys such as ü with Linux looks same here, totally broken, two chars appear: http://www.bgxcomponents.com/flashValidateRegExp.htm

Comment: How is the input wrong under Linux?  What are the values for `KeyboardEvent.charCode`, `String.fromCharCode` and `String.toLowerCase` on Linux when you try to type a Ü?

Comment: the output of foreign keys with Linux looks same here, totally broken: http://www.bgxcomponents.com/flashValidateRegExp.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be [this](https://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/FP-660) Flash Player bug.